# Footer Item aren't getting aligned properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am not able to understand why is it happening that there is some left margin in footer 2 item1. Though I haven't given. Please help.

[image]

```css
.footer1,
.footer2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(243, 242, 242);
}

.footer2 ul {
  display: flex;
}

.footer2 ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer1">Item1</div>
  <div class="footer2">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.footer1,
.footer2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(243, 242, 242);
}

.footer2 ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer2 ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer1">Item1</div>
  <div class="footer2">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

`ul` tag has default `padding`. so If you want to remove some gap in `ul`, you can set `padding: 0`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_lists

Answer (score 1):

This is because the browser's user agent stylesheet adds `padding-inline-start: 40px;` for `ul`

setting it to 0 will fix your problem

```css
.footer1,
.footer2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(243, 242, 242);
}

.footer2 ul {
  display: flex;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.footer2 ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer1">Item1</div>
  <div class="footer2">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```